# How to preserve generic type when passing parameters forward?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

It seems as though `typeof` a function or class with generic parameters replaces all of the generics with `unknown`.  Is there a way to preserve that information?

For example, the variables `exampleNumber` and `exampleString` below will be of type `Example<unknown>`, but my goal is for them to be `Example<number>` and `Example<string>` respectively.

```js
class Example<T> {
    constructor(public value: T) {}
}

function newExample(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Example>) {
    return new Example(...args);
}

const exampleNumber = newExample(3);
const exampleString = newExample('foo');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's type system does not have [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) of the sort needed to directly represent the operation you're trying to do.  Before TypeScript 3.4/3.5 I'd say that the only way for you to proceed is to manually write out the function typing you want:

```
function newExampleManual<T>(...args: [T]) {
  return new Example(...args);
}
```

TypeScript 3.4 introduced some support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) and TypeScript 3.5 introduced the analogous support for [generic constructors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-constructors), which gives you a way to get the function type you want... with the proviso that this doesn't happen purely at the type level: instead you need to represent the transformation as the effect of a generic function that accepts other (possibly generic) functions or constructors as callbacks.

Specifically:

```
const ctorToFn =
  <A extends any[], R>(ctor: new (...args: A) => R) => (...args: A) => new ctor(...args);
        
const newExample = ctorToFn(Example);
// const newExample: <T>(value: T) => Example<T>
```

You can see that `ctorToFn()` turns any constructor into a function in the obvious way: use the passed arguments to invoke the construct signature of the constructor.  Then `ctorToFn(Example)` produces the `newExample` implementation you want, more or less... and automagically, it also gives it the *type signature* you want: namely the generic function type `<T>(value: T) => Example<T>`.

Then this works as desired:

```
const exampleNumber = newExample(3);
// const exampleNumber: Example<number>
const exampleString = newExample('foo');
// const exampleString: Example<string>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTAPAFQHzQG8AoaaYAewDsIAXAJwFdgby6AKFBgIxAEthoANzAgG6AFzRsASkLQAvkUVEAZg0rNeVaJXQB3BMjToAsmEoMROXGwB09sHQDmESQG1sAXVnFSddDQMdJQ6+nCIqBh2Ds4Q0gDcSkREFNQ0ZCx02OQAYiEAvCTQmACC0OjwNOiUACYw5gCebp4ANNAASjbMrJK6etDRto4ukiWy+fjt4-iDw67QY9ATof3d7PZDsQnJKVS0K4aR6EsZrNl5bIfG2wD0N2R76X1XGJLWbMKiElLT4UYY1mSqX2FX+6AAcgwkFx0HQTs8IsY2ABmW73YHpUFHSHQ2GSF5YCy4ui4XZpcqIjAAZXovEoTnh+gJbAA5CpyOQWWiHuSscYaXQ6U58ZSsLRBfTcEA)